# Trying to flatten data into columns within oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table in Oracle 12 and I need to flatten the table so that all the rows for edit_number are rolled up into one row with multiple columns. I've seen this before but I'm struggling to find a way to put them in specific columns. There is a maximum of 4 rows in the Edit_Raw_Table per Edit_Number

Edit_Raw_Table

```
+----------+-------------+---------+------------+------------+
| table_ID | Edit_Number | Edit_Ref| Edit_Text  | Edit_Valid |
+----------+-------------+---------+------------+------------+
|        1 |        3    |   10146 | REASON 123 |   YES      |
|        2 |        3    |   10169 | REASON 567 |   YES      |
|        3 |        3    |   10156 | REASON 456 |    NO      |
+----------+-------------+---------+------------+------------+
```

What I would like to do is have something like this:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+
| Edit_Number| Edit_Ref_1| Edit_Text_1| Edit_Ref_2 | Edit_Text_2 | 
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+
|       3    |   10146   | Reason 123 |    10169   |  Reason 567 |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: right, looks like it's something that would work in t-sql but not in PL/SQL. I wasn't sure if I should have included what I've tried.

Comment: I've removed the code as it's irrelevant to the end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of aggregation along with `decode` (or `case`, whichever you prefer; in this case, `decode` is quite simple) might do the job.

```
SQL> with edit_raw_table (table_id, edit_number, edit_ref, edit_text, edit_valid) as
  2    (select 1, 3, 10146, 'Reason 123', 'yes' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 3, 10169, 'Reason 567', 'yes' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 3, 10156, 'Reason 456', 'no'  from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 4, 8, 10111, 'reason 111', 'yes' from dual union all
  7     --
  8     select 5, 4, 20222, 'reason 222', 'no'  from dual union all
  9     select 6, 4, 20333, 'reason 333', 'yes' from dual union all
 10     select 7, 4, 20444, 'reason 444', 'yes' from dual union all
 11     select 8, 4, 20555, 'reason 555', 'yes' from dual
 12    ),
 13  temp as
 14    (select e.*,
 15            row_number() over (partition by edit_number order by table_id) rn
 16     from edit_raw_table e
 17     where edit_valid = 'yes'
 18    )
 19  select edit_number,
 20         max(decode(rn, 1, edit_ref)) edit_ref_1,
 21         max(decode(rn, 1, edit_text)) edit_text_1,
 22         --
 23         max(decode(rn, 2, edit_ref)) edit_ref_2,
 24         max(decode(rn, 2, edit_Text)) edit_text_2,
 25         --
 26         max(decode(rn, 3, edit_ref)) edit_ref_3,
 27         max(decode(rn, 3, edit_Text)) edit_text_3,
 28         --
 29         max(decode(rn, 4, edit_ref)) edit_ref_4,
 30         max(decode(rn, 4, edit_Text)) edit_text_4
 31  from temp
 32  group by edit_number
 33  order by edit_number;

EDIT_NUMBER EDIT_REF_1 EDIT_TEXT_ EDIT_REF_2 EDIT_TEXT_ EDIT_REF_3 EDIT_TEXT_ EDIT_REF_4 EDIT_TEXT_
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          3      10146 Reason 123      10169 Reason 567
          4      20333 reason 333      20444 reason 444      20555 reason 555
          8      10111 reason 111

SQL>
```

Comment: This works, of course replacing the selected values with a select from the current table. Thank you!